# OCR with react-native and expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, ocr, image-recognition

I have an upcoming project to build an app that does OCR and i want to ask is there anyway to do ocr with react-native and expo because react-native is my preferred framework and expo makes it really easy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me, was to simply create a flask api for the OCR functionality.`react-native-tesseract-ocr` did not help at all.

Comment: what api did you use?

Answer (score 2):

There has been many ways currently provided in react native to do ocr. One of them, You can simply download `react-native-tesseract-ocr` and follow the instruction here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tesseract-ocr. There is also github link related that here https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out `react-native-mlkit-ocr` module for OCR on React native.
check it out [here!](https://github.com/agoldis/react-native-mlkit-ocr)